# module not found error on line "from include.data import get_data_set"

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science

I am not expert on tensorflow and was trying an example on CNN  from a site. Here is the link: https://www.edureka.co/blog/convolutional-neural-network/

When I try first few lines of this code example on Jupyter Notebook, then I get the error in the very beginning of the code on following two lines:
First few lines of code which throw an error are:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from time import time
import math


from include.data import get_data_set
from include.model import model, lr
```

I get the error for this line of code "from include.data import get_data_set. The error is: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'include.data'

If I remove this line of code, then I get the similar error for next line of code "from include.model import model, lr. The error is: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'include.model'

I searched on the google as well as on this site but could not find any helping page. I tried installing include using pip command but that did not help. Can you please let me know which module is missing or if I am missing something else. My guess is that there may be some code related to it on the example page which should be includes but I am not sure and could not find it either.

Please help how to fix this error.

Comment: Looks like the tutorial you're following doesn't supply any input data, find another tutorial.

Comment: try **import include** and see if you get the same error. if so, you might not have this library on your computer and you need to open your cmd and type **python -m pip install include**

Comment: I guess your tutorial is based on https://github.com/exelban/tensorflow-cifar-10. There you can find data you need

Comment: @Gal I already installed Include and tried with import include but then error remains there. With just 'Import Include' it does not import get_data_set and throws error about it

Comment: @A.Sizov Your response is very helpful. I can see the missing programs in the link you provided. Thank you so much